# Express: Does my code still run even after a response is sent?

Tags: javascript, express

I have code that basically looks like this:

```
return Promise.all([
  myPromise("foo", () => saveToFirebase("foo")),
  myPromise("bar", () => saveToFirebase("bar")),
  ... // 50 more of these ^ 
]).then(() => {
  res.status(200).send('ok');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('error');
});
```

My request times out because some of my requests take a long time. My question is: if I just called `res.status(200)` without chaining it `Promise.all`, would my unresolved promises still resolve even after a response is sent? Or would all execution of my code stop once a response is sent?

Like this:

```
Promise.all([
  myPromise("foo", () => saveToFirebase("foo")),
  myPromise("bar", () => saveToFirebase("bar")),
  ... // 50 more of these ^ 
])
res.status(200).send('ok');
```

Comment: No it wouldnt stop. It keeps running until your tasks are finished. .. However it will not show an error.

Comment: @Jonasw why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise will always be executed. As you can see in following picture after response is send `after promise resolve` is printed on console.

[image: Promise resolve after response is send]

And you can also keep the connection alive by setting `res.shouldKeepAlive` to true like this :

```
Promise.all([
        check(2),
        check(2),
        check(2)
    ]).then(() => {
        console.log('after promise resolve');
        setTimeout(function() {
            res.send('done');
        }, 10000);
    });
    console.log('Before promise resolve');
    res.shouldKeepAlive = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

All promises will be either resolved or rejected. Express does not stop any execution when you finish request. You can try it out by simple console log:

```
Promise.all([
  myPromise("foo", () => saveToFirebase("foo")),
  myPromise("bar", () => saveToFirebase("bar")),
  ... // 50 more of these ^ 
])
.then(() => console.log("promises resolved"))
.catch(err => console.error("promises rejected", err))
res.status(200).send('ok')
```

However with this approach you don't know if anything went wrong when sending response.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could keep the connection alive like this:

```
const keepalive = setInterval(_=>res.write("."),1000);

return Promise.all([
  myPromise("foo", () => saveToFirebase("foo")),
  myPromise("bar", () => saveToFirebase("bar")),
   ... // 50 more of these ^ 
]).then(() => {
  res.status(200).send('ok');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('error');
}).then(_=>clearInterval(keepalive));
```